How will we handle Building/Technique questions?
I have posted a technique question, but i see there is some uncertainty as to how we respond to them.
What will our policy be concerning these potentially open ended questions? I know of another SE site that seems to be able to handle them.
EDIT:
There seems to be a move for the  building tag to supersede the technique tag for these types of questions, but my concerns still apply. How will we handle these types of questions to make it clear to newcomers what our policy is?

It's a good question, and one that we'd started discussing a bit in chat too - a bit similar to the more general question raised on "open ended questions".
The technique tag is almost a "meta" tag, and as such has debatable use - if we keep the questions using it tightly focused, it could be quite useful.
That said, while Oezi's answer is the most correct (with a direct link to the building instructions), I'd like to see a little more detail in there (I'm building some examples in LDD to add to the answer).
